# Plyr, doMC and global variables

Tags: r, parallel-processing, plyr, domc

I use `R` (3.1) and `plyr` and `doMC` as parallel backend (as far as I know that's the only parallel backend that works with `plyr`)

My question is how can I write to global variables from within the working threads. I have this (very artificial) example:

```
library(doMC)
library(plyr)
registerDoMC(cores=2)

result1 = data.frame(id=c(1:3), a=NA)
result2 = data.frame(id=c(1:3), b=NA)

f = function(x){
    result1[ result1$id==x$id, "a"] <<- x$a
    result2[ result2$id==x$id, "b"] <<- x$b
}

data = data.frame(id=c(1:3), a=c(4:6), b=c(7:9))
a_ply(data, .margins=1, .fun=f, .parallel=T)
```

As I want to fill 2 dataframes I can't use `aaply` or `adply`. The example does what it is supposed to do with `parallel=FALSE`. When I do it parallel the result data.frames remain empty. I know that I have to export the global variables to the workers and i tried to use `.paropts=list(.export=c("result1", "result2"))` but that doesn't help....

Does anybody know how to export global variables to `doMC` workers? Or is there another solution which fills both data.frames in a parallel environment (mazbe without `plyr`?)

Comment: OT: `library(doParallel);registerDoParallel(2)` will work with plyr too. And every other parallel backend (doMPI, doSNOW).

Comment: no...`doMC` exports all the parameters plyr needs. See @hadley comment on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559287/how-do-i-make-dosmp-play-nicely-with-plyr

Comment: It was three years ago ;)

Comment: hmmm...however. doParallel does not work on my Ubuntu 64 bit system.

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify global object from parallel workers. That's why you need export your data.frames - workers can't access global environment and they change only exported **copy**.

You need to rewrite your function to return some kind of value, which later you can use to fill data.frame.